# How to stop Broadcast Receiver that used to block calls

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

I tried lot of links at so but I am not good enough to find the right code.I managed to block calls using this code.

```
public class BlockCallReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver{

    Context context;
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        Bundle myBundle = intent.getExtras();
        if (myBundle != null)
        {
            System.out.println("--------Not null-----");
            try
            {
                if (intent.getAction().equals("android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE"))
                {
                    String state = intent.getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE);
                    System.out.println("--------in state-----");
                    if (state.equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_RINGING))
                    {
                        // Incoming call
                        String incomingNumber =intent.getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_INCOMING_NUMBER);
                        System.out.println("--------------my number---------"+incomingNumber);

                         // this is main section of the code,. could also be use for particular number.
                        // Get the boring old TelephonyManager.
                        TelephonyManager telephonyManager =(TelephonyManager) context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);

                        // Get the getITelephony() method
                        Class<?> classTelephony = Class.forName(telephonyManager.getClass().getName());
                        Method methodGetITelephony = classTelephony.getDeclaredMethod("getITelephony");

                        // Ignore that the method is supposed to be private
                        methodGetITelephony.setAccessible(true);

                        // Invoke getITelephony() to get the ITelephony interface
                        Object telephonyInterface = methodGetITelephony.invoke(telephonyManager);

                        // Get the endCall method from ITelephony
                        Class<?> telephonyInterfaceClass = Class.forName(telephonyInterface.getClass().getName());
                        Method methodEndCall = telephonyInterfaceClass.getDeclaredMethod("endCall");

                        // Invoke endCall()
                        methodEndCall.invoke(telephonyInterface);

                    }

                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                // Many things can go wrong with reflection calls
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and in my Manifest

```
<receiver android:name=".utils.BlockCallReceiver" >
    <intent-filter android:priority="100" >
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE" >
    </action>
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

It worked. But even the app is no in foreground/or not even in the active apps calls are blocked.

I tried to un register this BlockCallReceiver class in my Launcher Activity because I want to allow calls when the app is not open.

So in `onPause` I tried some codes given in answers but It did not work since my bad knowledge.

Here is an example that I tried but I'm stuck

```
ComponentName receiver = new ComponentName(MainActivity.this, BlockCallReceiver.class);
PackageManager pm = MainActivity.this.getPackageManager();
pm.setComponentEnabledSetting(receiver, PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_ENABLED, PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP);
```

Please if someone can guide me to re allow calls when the app turns off I am really grateful.

**Edit One** :

If I use below

```
public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        MainActivity.this.unregisterReceiver(mybroadcast);
    }
```

It throws me an error `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException:` Receiver not registered! Yes I have not registered it in my Activity only on that thing at the manifest. I know something is wrong but cannot understand it.

**Edit Two** : @Imen Nmn answer is helpful. I will try to register dynamically rather than the Manifest. But I have a doubt there should be someway with un registering B.receiver given in the Manifest ?

Answer (score 1):

To Stop a broadcastReceiver , you should call :             **yourContext**.unregisterReceiver(**yourBroadcastReceiver**);

if you notice this example , in **onResume** there is **this.registerReceiver(the_receiver, filter);** and in **onPause** , there is

**this.unregisterReceiver(the_receiver);**

Here an example :

public class Android Example extends Activity {

```
                        private BroadcastReceiver the_receiver = new BroadcastReceiver(){

                                @Override
                                public void onReceive(Context c, Intent i) {

                                }
                        };
                        // Set When broadcast event will fire.
                        private IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_CONFIGURATION_CHANGED);

                        @Override
                        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                             super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                             setContentView(R.layout.main);
                        }

                        @Override
                        protected void onResume() {

                            // Register reciever if activity is in front
                            this.registerReceiver(the_receiver, filter);
                            super.onResume();
                        }

                        @Override
                        protected void onPause() {

                             // Unregister reciever if activity is not in front
                             this.unregisterReceiver(the_receiver);
                             super.onPause();
                        }

                }
```

Comment: Hi Bro, should i call it in my Launcher Activity ? i will try this with onPause and let you know. If  I am wrong please correct me

Comment: Call it in onPause and  let me know if it works or not ;) . You can see this link . It might be useful http://androidexample.com/Introduction_To_Broadcast_Receiver_Basics/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=60

Comment: It crashed, I update my question, it says i have not registered  Receiver, can you kindly tell me do i need to register it also in my Launcher activity? Everything works as the way it is, but when i close the app still the calls are blocked.That need be solved -_- help me

Comment: You should add it dynamically not from the manifest. Then , you should register it where you need it and unregister it when you don't need it. 
In this link http://androidexample.com/Introduction_To_Broadcast_Receiver_Basics/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=60  will show you two ways to use broadcastreceiver take a look and if you don't understand a thing tell me :)

Comment: I read what you gave, its helpful it says there are two ways to have a broadcast receiver. Manifest or dynamically . So my one goes with Manifest .but that link does not say how to stop it :[

Comment: Okay ill try dinamically

Comment: If you notice in onResume , he registered the broadcast and in onPause he unregistred. I will show you an example

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/138114/discussion-between-imen-nmn-and-sanuka-hasith).